# What is the name of this plug, and which side is line and which is neutral?

Tags: connector, plug, power-connector, ac-polarity

What is the name of this plug, and which side is line and which is neutral?
[image]

(Image from [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:IEC60320_Polarised_C7.JPG))

Answer (score 1):

> What is the name of this plug

The displayed plug is a polarized C7.

> which side is line and which is neutral?

According to [an image at Wikimedia commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:IEC60320_Polarised_C7_Polarity.jpg), the square side is neutral and the rounded side is "line" or "live".

[image]

As pointed out in a comment by jonathanjo, the polarized C7 is not part of the IEC 60320 standard, and the wikimedia image has been alternating between square is neutral and square is line.

Finbarr has pointed out in a comment that the non-polarized C7 plug will fit into a polarized socket, and that polarized to non-polarized cables are commercially available, making the polarized C7 of questionable value.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [IEC 60320](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320) says that C7 polarized is **not part of the standard**; the image at [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:IEC60320_Polarised_C7_Polarity.jpg) has been alternating between square-is-neutral and square-is-live.

Comment: The daft thing about this is that the non-polarised C7 plug will fit into the polarised socket - and you can buy leads with a polarised connector one end and a non-polarised on the other. Hard to see what reason there is for using the polarised version.